# What should I call this function when we share some content to an app?

Tags: android, ios

When we share some web content to an app(eg. Instagram),
we can see some popped up displays like 1) and 2)

**What should I call the terminologies or fucntions abt 1) and 2) ?**

1. In my phone, content - touch the share button - a popped up screen is appeared
   [image]

---

2. When I touch an app(eg. Instagram) - a popped up screen is appeard
   [image]

Comment: Have a look at Intent.ACTION_SEND and others.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:
[Sharing Simple Data | Android](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing)